# Como hacer un ciclo para que lea todo el archivo de texto y pasarlo a una lista?

Tags: c

Tengo el siguiente archivo de texto separado por comas:

> Lopez,95128428,Chile\n Lee,148284,China\n Condrio,95182,Brasil\n
> Goku,591281,Japon\n

El primer dato es el apellido, el segundo es el DNI y el ultimo es el pais.

Lo que tengo que hacer es pasar este archivo a una lista en el cual cada uno de los nodos contiene a una estructura que es en donde voy a guardar los datos del archivo.

El problema que estoy teniendo es que no se muy bien como hacer para que me lea todas las lineas, osea quiero hacer un while, pero como estoy leyendo cada uno de los campos en funciones, no se muy bien como hacer para hacer un while que termine y no puedo modificar el archivo.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct s_datos
{
    char*apellido;
    int dni;
    char*pais;
};
typedef struct s_datos t_dato;

struct s_nodo
{
    t_dato dato;
    struct s_nodo*sig;
};
typedef struct s_nodo*t_nodo;

char* sacoapellido(FILE*arch);
int sacodocumento(FILE*arch);
char*sacopais(FILE*arch);
void agregar(t_nodo*,t_dato);
void imprimir(t_nodo);

int main()
{
    t_nodo lista=NULL;
    t_dato aux;
    char*txt=NULL;
    char*txt2=NULL;
    int r,i=0,doc;

    FILE*arch=NULL;
    arch=fopen("personas.txt","r");
    txt=sacoapellido(arch);
    doc=sacodocumento(arch);
    txt2=sacopais(arch);

    aux.apellido=txt;
    aux.dni=doc;
    aux.pais=txt2;

    agregar(&lista,aux);
    txt=sacoapellido(arch);
    doc=sacodocumento(arch);
    txt2=sacopais(arch);
    aux.apellido=txt;
    aux.dni=doc;
    aux.pais=txt2;
    agregar(&lista,aux);
   // printf("\nLos datos son: Apellido : %s - DNI: %d  - Pais: %s",aux.apellido,aux.dni,aux.pais);
    imprimir(lista);


}
char*sacoapellido(FILE*arch)
{
    int i=0,r;
    char*aux=NULL;
    aux=malloc(sizeof(char));
    r=fgetc(arch);
    while(r!=',')
    {
        *(aux+i)=r;
        i++;
        aux=realloc(aux,(i+1)*sizeof(char));
        r=fgetc(arch);
    }
    *(aux+i)='\0';
    return aux;
}
int sacodocumento(FILE*arch)
{
    int documento;
    fscanf(arch,"%d,",&documento);
    return documento;

}
char*sacopais(FILE*arch)
{
    int i=0,r;
    char*aux=NULL;
    aux=malloc(sizeof(char));
    r=fgetc(arch);
    while(r!='\n' && r!=EOF)
    {
        *(aux+i)=r;
        i++;
        aux=realloc(aux,(i+1)*sizeof(char));
        r=fgetc(arch);
    }
    *(aux+i)='\0';
    return aux;
}
void agregar(t_nodo*nodo,t_dato dato)
{
    if(*nodo==NULL)
    {
        *nodo=(t_nodo)malloc(sizeof(struct s_nodo));
        (*nodo)->dato=dato;
        (*nodo)->sig=NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        agregar(&(*nodo)->sig,dato);
    }
}
void imprimir(t_nodo lista)
{
    while(lista!=NULL)
    {
        printf("Apellido: %s - DNI: %d - Pais: %s\n",lista->dato.apellido,lista->dato.dni,lista->dato.pais);
        lista=lista->sig;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cuando una función no logró leer algo, es el fin de archivo (o un error).

En  `sacopais` se puede verificar eso muy dimplemente: si `i == 0`, estás al fin de archivo. Podéis hacer

```
if (i == 0) {
   free(aux);
   aux = NULL;
}
return aux;
```

En `sacodocumento`, *debes* verificar el código de retorno de `fscanf`. Decide qué devolver en caso de error, pr ejemplo -1.

En tu `main`, podéis hacer

```
 while ((txt  = sacoapellido  (arch)) != NULL   && 
        (doc  = sacodocumento (arch)) != -1     &&  
        (txt2 = sacopaois     (arch)) != NULL)
 {
    // añadir un nodo 
 }
```

Algunas notas al margen. Primero, `aux[i]` siempre es mejor que `(*aux+i)`. Segundo, tienes dos funcionas casi idénticas, `sacopais` y `sacoapellido`, intenta unificarlas.